# Running a libraby for fuzzy logic classification (jfuzzylogic) on Android?

Tags: java, android, jfuzzylogic

I have implemented code that classifies hand gestures into the correct corresponding letters and words as a Java application.

What am trying to do now is to implement my classification algorithm on android so that i am able to classify these gestures by processing the input data on my Android device.

Can i use "jfuzzylogic" in Android, and if not is there a alternative to this library that could run in Android?

Comment: Yes, but what happen when you try to upload to Google play, google said that jFuzzyLogic uses some native libraries antlrworks-1.2.jar, jcommon-1.0.14.jar, jfreechart-1.0.11.jar, and tell me that 0 devices supported...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use jfuzzylogic in Android, as it is standard Java.

Comment: is jfuzzylogic considered standard java?

Comment: Yes, it appears to be written solely in standard Java with no accompanying C or other malarkey.

Answer (score 0):

Use jfuzzylite instead. It is free and open source. It does not require third-party libraries, contains more features than jfuzzylogic (except for parameter optimization), and the binary size is less than 300KB. Visit www.fuzzylite.com.